# How to update specific records in database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have one drop down and lists are aMan, bMan, cMan.I am selecting any one of them from drop down. So whatever I am selecting from drop down I want to update that records according to list. Below update query is updating all my records because i added '$action_points' for each.

For example. If I selected bMan from the drop down then in update table will update only bMan records according to user_id.If I select aMan then update table it will update only aMan with 10.It will not effect on other.

I am getting the issue on update query.Would you help me with update query?

```
$result = $conn->query($sql_user);
 if (isset($result->num_rows) > 0) {
 // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $action_type=$row['action_type'];// Value will be aMan,bMan, cMan 
  $action_points=$row['action_points']; //10, 20, 30     
   }
  }
 $sql = "UPDATE man SET aMan='$action_points',bMan='$action_points', cMan='$action_points' where user_id='$user_id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Update table

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting from select drop down it means it will pass the value, that you have either aMan, bMan or cMan.

so you can do it like this,

```
$action_type = $_GET['action_type'];

$sql = "update man set `$action_type` = '$action_value' where id = $user_id";
```

Above is an example.

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Abhishek.I remove the single quote from $action_type then It working.Thanks for the help.Upvote from my side

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should replace `if (isset($result -> num_rows) >0 )` with `if(isset($result)) && ($result->num_rows>0))` .The first condition returns the number of rows (which at the least is 0) and then checks if it is set. Thus, `isset` will always return true, even when `$result` is not set. The second condition solves this problem

You have the `type` of list to update, why don't you use it?

For eg:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql_user);
 if(isset($result)) && ($result->num_rows>0)) {
 // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $action_type=$row['action_type'];// Value will be aMan,bMan, cMan 
  $action_points=$row['action_points']; //10, 20, 30     
   }
  }
 $sql = "UPDATE man SET $action_type = $action_points WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

This shall automatically update the required column

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Fabulous. upvote from my side.Your query is simple and easy

Comment: Also, you should replace `if (isset($result -> num_rows) >0 )` with `if(isset($result)) && ($result->num_rows>0))` .The first condition returns the number of rows (which at the least is 0) and then checks if it is set. Thus, `isset` will always return `true`, even when `$result` is not set. The seconf condition solves this problem

Answer (score 0):

U should use AND in your query

```
UPDATE man SET aMan='$action_points' AND bMan='$action_points' AND cMan='$action_points' where user_id='$user_id'"
```

Or use several update query it means once update aMan row then a query for bMan row and so on.

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.arash. above query is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you are updating the three column at a time, you have to make it conditional like:

```
$action_type=$row['action_type'];// Value will be aMan,bMan, cMan 
$action_points=$row['action_points']; //10, 20, 30     

$column = '';
if($action_type == 'aMan'){
    $column = 'aMan';
}
else if($action_type == 'bMan'){
    $column = 'bMan';
}
else if($action_type == 'cMan'){
    $column = 'cMan';
}

$sql = "UPDATE man SET ".$column." = '".$action_points."' where user_id='$user_id'";
```